# HQL/SQL - Return records that have any one of multiple values in a date field

Tags: sql, hibernate, date, hql

I would like to be able to write queries where only records are returned which have a specific field value consisting of one or more dates in a list.

for example(and I thought this would work but it doesn't):

```
select * from someDatabase.someTable where dateField in ('2017-11-10','2017-11-14','2017-11-28');
```

So I was hoping that this would only return records where dateField contained any one or all of the dates in `('2017-11-10','2017-11-14','2017-11-28')`

When I run a query like this I get the error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:105 Wrong arguments ''2017-11-20'': The arguments for IN should be the same type! Types are: {date IN (string, string)}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the arguments inside the `IN` to `date`, using the `CAST` function.

```
CAST( expression AS type )
```

This is how should be your query:

```
select * from someDatabase.someTable where dateField in (cast('2017-11-10' as date),cast('2017-11-14' as date),cast('2017-11-28' as date))
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the structure of your table using:

```
describe extended someDatabase.someTable;
```

This looks like a datatype mismatch error as your dateField seems to be a Map and not Date.

Ideally date comparisons are as below (cant test right now for syntax):

```
select * from someDatabase.someTable where dateField in ((from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-11-10', 'YYYY-MM-dd'),'YYYY-MM-dd'),(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-11-14', 'YYYY-MM-dd'),'YYYY-MM-dd'),(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017-11-28','YYYY-MM-dd'));
```

Comment: The data type is listed as 'date' for the field in question.

Comment: @Dr.Tautology the converstion string 'YYYY-MM-DD' inside the select cast should match the format of your dateField.